# How to use pdf2Dom library in java code to get html doc from pdf?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to extract tabular data from PDF, and to start it, my first step of algorithm says to convert PDF to html doc.
How can I convert PDF to html using **pdf2Dom library**?

Comment: thankyou for the edit - InsaneCat

Comment: PDFBox (according to tag) or Pdf2Dom (according to question text), which library are you talking about?

Comment: Ah, I just saw that pdf2Dom is based on PDFBox.

Comment: Yes, PDF2DOM is based on PDFBOX.......But I am talking about , how can I use PDf2DOM library to get HTML DOC from pdf.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it using this

```
private void generateHTMLFromPDF(String filename) {
    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(filename));
    Writer output = new PrintWriter("src/output/pdf.html", "utf-8");
    new PDFDomTree().writeText(pdf, output);
    output.close();
}
```

reference - [link](https://www.baeldung.com/pdf-conversions-java)